# How do I convert an image size(width / height) to mm?

Tags: c#, math, image-processing, coordinates, pixel

Im working on inspecting a sheet of paper sized 250mm(width) to 150mm(height).
I grab the image and process it to get the relevant points in mm to send to a robot.
This is how im converting pixel to mm :

```
decimal paperW = image.Width / 250;
decimal paperH = image.Height / 150;
```

but this is not accurate, the points are shifted 15mm to the top. Resolution is 96 dpi.

How do I accurately convert image size to mm? Please help.

Comment: The amount of details you provide is severely lacking. What image? What robot? What APIs are you using?

Comment: haha, how does what robot and API's im using of any concern? Even if i dont have any robot and if I plot the point manually on the image of 2500 x 1500 px, say Point p = new Point (200,200). And then I convert this point to mm, I should be able to measure this point with a scale on the said paper. Using the formula I used, The point is shifted 15mm upwards.

Comment: Why don't you show a sample image. In which angle you take the picture? What points are shifted? Do you want the size of the CCD or just size an object in the image??

Answer (score 1):

The general formula to convert a number of pixels in millimeters is the following:

`decimal millimeters = (pixels * 25.4d) / dpi;`

The constant 25.4 is simply the amount of millimeters in an inch, since we convert from the DPI (Dots per *inch*) to millimeters.

As an example, with your values of 96 DPIs and a point at 200 pixels, this would mean a corresponding point at `(200 * 25.4) / 96 = 52.91mm`

---

If you need to do the opposite, find the the amount of pixels for a length, the formula becomes:

`decimal pixels = (millimeters * dpi) / 25.4d;`

Say you have a sheet of 250mm of paper still at 96 DPI, this means it is `(250 * 96) / 25.4 = 944 pixels` long